# Generating palindromes

Tags: c, algorithm, palindrome

Recently I wrote this quick'n'dirty code, which generates palindromes as follows:

```
int main() {
    generateEvenPalindromes(1);
}

unsigned long generateEvenPalindromes(int lowerBound) {
    unsigned long palindrome = 0;
    int upperBound = lowerBound * 10;

    for (int i = lowerBound; i < upperBound; i++) {
        palindrome = appendMirroredValueToNum(i, -1);    // -1 means 'no middle digit'
        printf("%lu\n", palindrome);
    }
    return generateOddPalindromes(lowerBound);
}

unsigned long generateOddPalindromes(int lowerBound) {
    unsigned long palindrome = 0;
    int upperBound = lowerBound * 10;

    for (int i = lowerBound; i < upperBound; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            palindrome = appendMirroredValueToNum(i, j);
            printf("%lu\n", palindrome);
        }
    }
    if (upperBound > 10000) {
        return 0;
    }
    return generateEvenPalindromes(upperBound);
}

unsigned long appendMirroredValueToNum(int num, int middleDigit) {
    //...
    return newNumber;
}
```

– it produces a sequence of **aa** and **aba** palindromes, where a [1;99999], b [0;9], i.e.

```
11
22
...
99
101
111
121
...
217712
218812
219912
...
99999899999
99999999999
```

– and I was thinking of taking functions *generateEvenPalindromes()* and *generateOddPalindromes()* and combining them into one. If you think this is a good idea, can you please recommend a good approach to achieve this?

Comment: There are no _methods_ in your code. Only _functions_. C does not support _methods_ anyway.

Comment: And this is no code review site.

Comment: Those aren't permutations. A permutation is a reordering of a list of items. 312 is a permutation of 123. 333 is not.

Comment: The word you're looking for is palindromes.

Comment: Thanks y'all for your feedback, it was really helpful.

Comment: @rici I'm pretty sure palindrome can be described as a special case of permutation with repetition.

Comment: @wintermute, what's wrong with the code? I find this piece of code rather interesting and approach rather amusing. Whatever you have done is being done in min time (complexity). If you want to refactor it, instead of writing another function for odd length palindromes, you can use a flag in the function.

Comment: @vish4071 Thanks! I was just trying to find some balance between code readability and 'do not repeat yourself' principle. I guess, I should leave it as is